# Where does the Rep go when an answer is deleted?

Tags: discussion

I was performing reviews and down voted an answer...-1 rep and I get that. Now it seems that answer may be deleted. I went through my voting stuff and do not see it in there. I thought before that when a answer was DV'd and later deleted (say it was SPAM, I down vote, it is deleted) that the rep came back. It seems this is not the case anymore?

I know it is only one rep, that is not my concern. Just wondering if something has changed or maybe I am not seeing that vote I cast in my history.

Comment: It *eventually* comes back, but IIRC its done during a recalculation.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek - should I see a -1 and a +1? I'll keep an eye on it. :)

Comment: http://superuser.com/users/150754/carl-b?tab=reputation I see a +1 there on nov 4. You MAY need to squint tho ;p

Comment: @JourneymanGeek - I only see the last rep activity as oct 23. The rep bubble(top left next to StackExchange) is what I noticed went down, but never went up. I wonder whats up with that?

Comment: Found that I did not have the "Show removed..." box checked...now I see everything.